# BackHandler não funciona

Tags: react-native, expo, pwa

No meu app React-Native PWA o botão de voltar do Android está fechando o aplicativo.
Tentei usar essa função BackHandler dentro de uma tela qualquer para fazer ela voltar em vez de fechar o app mas não funciona. Alguém já passou por isso e tenha uma solução?

```
  useFocusEffect(useCallback(() => { 
    const onBackPress = () => {
      goBack();
      return true
    };

    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

    return () =>
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
  }, []));
```

Não funciona no PWA.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]. Aqui o conteúdo é em português, mas você pode fazer a sua pergunta em inglês no [so]. Sobre sua dúvida existe alguma tela na "pilha" de navegação? Porque se não houver, o Android de fato sai do aplicativo como comportamento padrão

Comment: Existe uma pilha criada com o createStackNavigator. As rotas funcionam normal e voltam normal com o botão de back do header no PWA. O problema é só o botão de voltar do android mesmo. Ele fecha o app tanto no PWA instalado como usando só no browser

Answer (score 0):

Eu segui esse exemplo e funcionou pra mim. Criei o meu próprio BackHandler

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/pull/1738#issuecomment-816992108

Answer (score 0):

Você pode abstrair em algo semelhante:

```
const onBackPress = useCallback(
    () => {
      if(isFocused){
        navigation.goBack();
        return true
      }
      return false
    }, [isFocused],
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
  }, [])
```